# xoring negative number doesn't return the same value with ^ and xor()

Tags: byte, python-3.6, xor

I don't understand why these doesn't return the same values.

```py
150 ^ -91

-205
```

but

```py
from pwn import *
xor(150,-91)

b'3'
```

Of course, `chr(-205)` is invalid and different to '3'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the library [packs](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools/blob/4.7.0/pwnlib/util/fiddling.py#L325) the arguments into unsigned values:

```
strs = [packing.flat(s, word_size = 8, sign = False, endianness = 'little') for s in args]
```

The [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation for `-91` is `0b10100101` in binary, that's `165` when converted to unsigned integer:

```
>>> 0b10100101
165
>>> from pwn import *
>>> flat(150, word_size=8, sign=False, endianness='little')
b'\x96'
>>> flat(-91, word_size=8, sign=False, endianness='little')
b'\xa5'
>>> 0x96
150
>>> 0xa5
165
>>> 150 ^ 165
51
>>> chr(51)
'3'
```